# Dereferenced vs non Dereferenced pointers ( and the explanation behind them )

Tags: c, pointers

Why is it we have to dereference a pointer ( that has already been linked to another variable ) every time we want to work on the variable its linked to? If there's  a pointer that's linked to a variable ( an int for example ) isn't dereferencing it on-top of everything else a bit redundant? Do standard ( non-dereferenced ) pointers serve their own separate purposes? What can we do with a pointer that hasn't been dereferenced?

example : `pPrice` vs `*pPrice`

I'm learning my first programming language C and I've been wondering this for some time.

Comment: A pointer is nothing but a variable that stores the *address of* something else as its value. (e.g. `int a = 2; int *b = &a;`) where `b` stores the *address of* `a` (or in other words `b` points to `a`). To get the value stored at the address held by `b`, you *dereference* `b`. Meaning, you ask `b` not for its value (e.g. the *address of* `a`), but for the value at that address. To get the value at the address held by `b`, you *dereference* the variable. (it is an indirect reference, the `'*'` gets rid of one level of indirection)

Answer (score 1):

When working with people who haven't worked with pointers before, I like to point out that a pointer isn't special compared to other primitive types; it's simply an integer, just like `int`s or `char`s. What's special about it is how we *interpret* its value - specifically, we interpret its value as the location (address) of another value. This is a little bit similar to how even though `char`s are really just integers, we *interpret* them to be characters based the ASCII encoding. Simply because we interpret a pointer's value to be an address, we can perform operations such as reading or writing the memory at the address it's specifying.

Like you said, we can still access the pointed to memory as usual, but now we have some additional benefits.

For example, we can change the pointer's value, thereby pointing it to a different place in memory. This might be useful if we want to write a generic function that modifies a given object, but you want to dynamically decide which object to pass to it.

Also, the pointer itself is a constant, defined size (usually 32 or 64 bits), yet it could point to an object of any arbitrary size (e.g. a `vector`, `string`, or a user defined type). This makes it possible for us to pass around or store a handle to the object without passing/storing the entire object, which might be expensive.

I'm sure there are a million more use cases that I'm leaving out, but these are a couple to get you started.

Comment: "*it's simply an integer*" well, well not really. It *can be* represented by an integer, but it not necessarily *is* an integer. See also: http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: An integer variable is distinct from a reference to an integer variable.

In C, the idea of a "variable" is very specific. In reality, it is the area in memory which holds the value of a variable. The symbol is a convenient symbol name by which the C code can refer to the value, to the content of the memory area. A "reference" is the address of the memory location. Since C is strongly typed, each symbol indicates how to interpret the memory to which it is associated. (Whew!)

So,

```
int i;
```

`i` refers to a memory location which holds an integer.

```
i=5;
```

fills that memory location with the binary representation for `5`.

```
int *p;
```

means `p` is associated with a memory location which contains a pointer (aka address) to an integer location. So we can write,

```
p = &i;
```

where `&i` is the explicit address of the memory location of the integer value. So, `p` and `i` refer to quite different kinds of things. Since `p` is the address of an integer, we can *dereference* it (i.e., follow the address) to get to the actual integer value at the address location (the one assocated with `i`).

```
*p = 6;
i = 6;
```

Both assignment statements are functionally equivalent (they both set the same memory location to integer 6) since both `i` and the dereferenced `p`, `*p`, refer to the same memory location. Noteably, `i` is inextricably tied to the memory location, while `*p` can *point* elsewhere (though, `p` is inextricably to the integer-pointer memory location that refers to integers).

Comment: What on earth is *Too Long Didn't Read* in that question?

Comment: :-) Does that mean you approve, @DavidC.Rankin? Thinking about the uninitiated, as I inferred from the original post, it might have been a bit much. As I write this comment, I realize that there was nothing superfluous, however; and nothing that a decent C programmer isn't acutely aware. Perhaps I should strike the "tl;dr"?

Comment: Yes, it was great, but it left me scratching my head wondering how one-paragraph was too long?? (2 paragraphs -- maybe, but one...)

Comment: Anyway, the "tl;dr" moniker, in some circles, has come to imply a summary of the "long" prose.

Answer (score 0):

`pPrice` may be modified to point to a different `price`.

```
int a = 1,
    b = 2,
    *p = &a;
printf("%d\n", *p);
p = &b;
printf("%d\n", *p);
```